# Discontinuity points of second kind and martingales

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, stochastic-processes, martingales

I was reading Rao book: stochastic processes and integration.

I came across the following theorem, where in the proof he mentioned that iii) is like i), but I can't see how, especially how is that for almost every $\omega,X_{\cdot}(\omega)$
has a left limit at every point $t$ ($\omega$ doesn't depend on the point we are choosing).

***Update:*** ***It's possible to prove iii) if we proved the following property for functions: if $f:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ a function bounded on compact and with no discontinuity points of second kind (the limit exist at right and left of every point of the domain), then $h(u)=\liminf_{r \downarrow u,r \in \mathbb{Q}}f(r)$ is right-continuous on $\mathbb{R}.$***

***This is exercise 6 page 171 from the following book: Random Walk, Brownian Motion, and Martingales (link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-78939-8)***

[image]
[image]

Comment: Jump distcontinuity means in general left and right limit exists but not equal to each other. See what is the definition in your book. If this is your definition then 3 and 1 are same except that you need to prove 3) also for boundary points of $T$.

Comment: what is II.8.14 that Rao mentions?

Answer (score 0):

If this is not what you're looking for, I can delete the answer.
It seems that Prop. 1.113 in Liggett's *Continuous Time Markov Processes* book is similar to what you're looking for:

> We conclude this section with two technical results that will be needed in Chapter 3. The boundedness assumption in the first can of course be weakened.
>
> **Proposition 1.113**. Suppose $\left(M(t), t \in Q^{+}\right)$is a uniformly bounded submartingale or supermartingale. Then with probability one,
> $$
> \lim _{s \uparrow t, s \in Q} M(s) \text { exists for every } t>0
> $$
> and
> $$
> \lim _{s \downarrow t, s \in Q} M(s) \text { exists for every } t \geq 0 .
> $$
> **Proof**. By replacing $M(t)$ by a linear function of $M(t)$, we may assume that $M(t)$ is a nonnegative submartingale. As in the proof of Theorem 1.92, with probability one, for every choice of rational $a<b$, the number of upcrossings by $\left(M(t), t \in Q^{+}\right)$from below $a$ to above $b$ is finite. Any such function has right and left limits as asserted.

The relevant part of the proof of Thm. 1.92 mentioned in the excerpt is:

> **Theorem 1.92 (Convergence theorem)**. If $\{M(t), t \geq 0\}$ is a right continuous submartingale that satisfies $\sup _t E|M(t)|<\infty$, then $\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} M(t)$ exists and is finite a.s. If, in addition, $M(t)$ is uniformly integrable, then the convergence also occurs in $L_1$.
>
> **Proof**. Recall that given a real sequence $\left\{x_0, \ldots, x_n\right\}$ and $a<b$, the number of upcrossings from below $a$ to above $b$ is the maximal value of $k$ so that
> there exist indexes $0 \leq j_1<j_2<\cdots<j_{2 k} \leq n$ satisfying $x_{j_i} \leq a$ for odd $i$ and $x_{j_i} \geq b$ for even $i$. For a function $x_t$ of a real argument, the number of upcrossings is the supremum of the number of upcrossings by $x_{t_1}, \ldots, x_{t_n}$ over all choices $t_1<\cdots<t_n$. Since $M\left(t_1\right), \ldots, M\left(t_n\right)$ is a discrete time submartingale for any such choice, the upcrossing inequality, Theorem A.43, gives
> $$ \text{$E \#\left\{\right.$ upcrossings by $M\left(t_1\right), \ldots, M\left(t_n\right)$ from below $a$ to above $\left.b\right\}$}
> \leq \frac{E M^{+}\left(t_n\right)+|a|}{b-a} \leq \frac{C+|a|}{b-a}
> $$
> where $C=\sup _t E|M(t)|<\infty$. Enumerating the positive rationals, applying this bound to the first $n$ placed in increasing order, and using the monotone convergence theorem gives the same bound for
> $$\text{$E \#\{$ upcrossings by $\{M(t), t \in Q \cap[0, \infty)\}$ from below $a$ to above $b\}$}.$$
> ...
>
> Considering only rational $a, b$, it then follows that with probability $1$, the number of upcrossings from below $a$ to above $b$ is finite a.s. for all $a, b$. ...

Comment: II.8.14 refers to the up-crossing inequality.

Comment: The question is how the proofs of i) and iii) are similar

Comment: @mathex ok. At the very least, it seems the upcrossing inequality allows us to conclude (iii) (and (i) as well?). As for asking how the proofs of (i) and (iii) are similar, it would help if you could rewrite Rao's proof of (i) in your own words with more fully explained terminology/notation (many phrases I don't understand: "fixed point of discontinuity", "closing on the right", the notation $X_{t_0^+}$, etc.). Frankly I don't really understand Rao's proof of (i), but if you put in the effort to explain (i) to us, people here might be more receptive of your question and more able to help.